Missing observations within nested random effects
I am trying to analyze height data collected from tree seedlings from multiple locations. At each location different treatments are applied in replicate blocks. At a two of the locations one species of seedling is missing (all of the planted seedlings died). The data looks like this:
data <- data.frame(location = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 8),
                   species = rep(c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"), times = 8),
                   trt =  rep(c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"), times = 4), 
                   block = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                   height = rnorm(32) + 10)

data <- data[!(data$location == "A" & data$species == "S4"), ]
data <- data[!(data$location == "B" & data$species == "S4"), ]

data


The model statement is am using is currently:
mod <- lmer(height ~ species * trt + (1|location/block), 
            data = data, REML = FALSE)

My question is with missing one species at a couple of the location (species S4 at location A and B) is this a valid model or am I introducing biases to the model coefficents by having an unbalanced experimental design? I am not interested in looking at the difference between "location" and "block" but I am interested in looking at the differences between treatment types and species.
Ignoring  warnings that come up with running this specific model as they dont come up when I run it on the real data.
Ive taken a look through many of the responses on both stack overflow and exchange but havent yet found a question looking at this issue.

Short answer: Yes, at least for the species in question.
Long answer: What do you mean with "missing"?
To answer this I thought it fitting to make a simulation and a few scenarios of why data might go missing and what one might do as a response.

Case 0: everything went to plan
Case 1: data went missing. Dave, the field technician, left his notes unattended and the wind took off with some of it. We have no idea what the heights were for one species at two locations.
Case 2: The plants failed to sprout. For whatever reason one of the species at two of the locations failed to sprout. Probably not a fluke, so we'll record the height as zero.
Case 3: The seedlings went missing. It might have been a deer that got through the fence and ate them, but we don't know. It's probably better to just remove the species that was affected altogether, as we can't attribute the partial missingness to anything.

Here's the simulation and the results for each of the four scenarios.
As you can see from the summaries, the estimates are the same, except for S4. Compared with Case 0, in Case 1 the estimate is higher, because the missing data was in the location/block that would have produced shorter seedlings. In Case 2 it's obviously much lower, because we coded the failed sprouting as zeroes. In Case 3 there is no S4.
The other species and treatment estimates are unaffected, while the S4 interactions are affected.
Standard error for S4 is affected, both in Case 1 because the number is reduced, and in Case 2 because variance is increased.
What should you do? That's determined by what you feel you can justify.
data0 <- expand.grid(
  block=c("1", "2"),
  location=c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  species=c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"),
  trt=c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"),
  rep=1:3
)

set.seed(1)
data0$height <- with(lapply(data0, as.numeric), {
      10 + 
      0.5*block +
      0.5*location + 
      0.5*species + 
      0.5*trt + 
      0.5*species*trt +
      0.5*block*location +
      rnorm(nrow(data0), 0, 2)
})

# Sanity check with a regular linear model.
# Estimates for the fixed effects should be the same as with lmer
summary(lmmod <- lm(height ~ location/block + species*trt, data=data0))
#
# Coefficients:
#                  Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
# ...snip
# speciesS2         0.89170    0.55406  1.6094 0.1084032    
# speciesS3         2.37137    0.55406  4.2800 2.397e-05 ***
# speciesS4         2.99510    0.55406  5.4058 1.175e-07 ***
# trtt2             1.63266    0.55406  2.9467 0.0034201 ** 
# trtt3             2.45394    0.55406  4.4290 1.256e-05 ***
# trtt4             2.39836    0.55406  4.3287 1.945e-05 ***
# speciesS2:trtt2   0.75106    0.78355  0.9585 0.3384389    
# speciesS3:trtt2   1.20322    0.78355  1.5356 0.1255136    
# ...snip

data3 <- data2 <- data1 <- data0

# Height data for S4 at loc A and B randomly missing 
# (a gust of wind took the notes)
data1 <- data1[!(data1$location == "A" & data1$species == "S4"), ]
data1 <- data1[!(data1$location == "B" & data1$species == "S4"), ]

# S4 at loc A and B failed to sprout, height recorded as 0
data2[(data2$location == "A" & data2$species == "S4"), "height"] <- 0
data2[(data2$location == "B" & data2$species == "S4"), "height"] <- 0

# Height data for S4 at loc A and B missing for unknown reasons
# (maybe a deer came over the fence and ate the seedlings?)
# Removing S4 altogether, just in case
data3 <- data3[data3$species != "S4", ]

mod0 <- lmer(height ~ species * trt + (1|location/block), data=data0, REML=FALSE)
mod1 <- lmer(height ~ species * trt + (1|location/block), data=data1, REML=FALSE)
mod2 <- lmer(height ~ species * trt + (1|location/block), data=data2, REML=FALSE)
mod3 <- lmer(height ~ species * trt + (1|location/block), data=data3, REML=FALSE)

summary(mod0, correlation=FALSE)
# ...snip
# Random effects:
#  Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#  block:location (Intercept) 1.7237   1.3129  
#  location       (Intercept) 1.0285   1.0142  
#  Residual                   3.5368   1.8806  
# Number of obs: 384, groups:  block:location, 8; location, 4
# 
# Fixed effects:
#                  Estimate Std. Error        df t value  Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)      15.08784    0.78738   6.61706 19.1622 4.806e-07 ***
# speciesS2         0.89170    0.54289 376.00001  1.6425  0.101323    
# speciesS3         2.37137    0.54289 376.00001  4.3680 1.623e-05 ***
# speciesS4         2.99510    0.54289 376.00001  5.5169 6.432e-08 ***
# trtt2             1.63266    0.54289 376.00001  3.0073  0.002813 ** 
# trtt3             2.45394    0.54289 376.00001  4.5201 8.292e-06 ***
# trtt4             2.39836    0.54289 376.00001  4.4177 1.306e-05 ***
# speciesS2:trtt2   0.75106    0.76777 376.00001  0.9782  0.328586    
# speciesS3:trtt2   1.20322    0.76777 376.00001  1.5672  0.117915    
# ...snip

summary(mod1, correlation=FALSE)
# ...snip
# Random effects:
#  Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#  block:location (Intercept) 1.87953  1.3710  
#  location       (Intercept) 0.61183  0.7822  
#  Residual                   3.56989  1.8894  
# Number of obs: 336, groups:  block:location, 8; location, 4
# 
# Fixed effects:
#                  Estimate Std. Error        df t value  Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)      15.08784    0.73256   7.20014 20.5960 1.153e-07 ***
# speciesS2         0.89170    0.54543 327.99470  1.6349 0.1030372    
# speciesS3         2.37137    0.54543 327.99470  4.3477 1.838e-05 ***
# speciesS4         3.60631    0.67694 328.52650  5.3274 1.853e-07 ***
# trtt2             1.63266    0.54543 327.99470  2.9934 0.0029688 ** 
# trtt3             2.45394    0.54543 327.99470  4.4991 9.486e-06 ***
# trtt4             2.39836    0.54543 327.99470  4.3972 1.484e-05 ***
# speciesS2:trtt2   0.75106    0.77135 327.99470  0.9737 0.3309272    
# speciesS3:trtt2   1.20322    0.77135 327.99470  1.5599 0.1197500    
# ...snip

summary(mod2, correlation=FALSE)
# ...snip
# Random effects:
#  Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#  block:location (Intercept)  1.1019  1.0497  
#  location       (Intercept) 13.9403  3.7337  
#  Residual                   26.2045  5.1190  
# Number of obs: 384, groups:  block:location, 8; location, 4
# 
# Fixed effects:
#                  Estimate Std. Error        df t value  Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)      15.08784    2.17133   6.52184  6.9487 0.0003051 ***
# speciesS2         0.89170    1.47774 376.00001  0.6034 0.5465924    
# speciesS3         2.37137    1.47774 376.00001  1.6047 0.1093926    
# speciesS4        -5.21246    1.47774 376.00001 -3.5273 0.0004717 ***
# trtt2             1.63266    1.47774 376.00001  1.1048 0.2699379    
# trtt3             2.45394    1.47774 376.00001  1.6606 0.0976263 .  
# trtt4             2.39836    1.47774 376.00001  1.6230 0.1054291    
# speciesS2:trtt2   0.75106    2.08984 376.00001  0.3594 0.7195083    
# speciesS3:trtt2   1.20322    2.08984 376.00001  0.5757 0.5651289    
# ...snip

summary(mod3, correlation=FALSE)
# ...snip
# Random effects:
#  Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#  block:location (Intercept) 1.70673  1.30642 
#  location       (Intercept) 0.71358  0.84474 
#  Residual                   3.63333  1.90613 
# Number of obs: 288, groups:  block:location, 8; location, 4
# 
# Fixed effects:
#                  Estimate Std. Error        df t value  Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)      15.08784    0.73697   7.20466 20.4728 1.194e-07 ***
# speciesS2         0.89170    0.55025 279.99999  1.6205 0.1062447    
# speciesS3         2.37137    0.55025 279.99999  4.3096 2.267e-05 ***
# trtt2             1.63266    0.55025 279.99999  2.9671 0.0032657 ** 
# trtt3             2.45394    0.55025 279.99999  4.4597 1.190e-05 ***
# trtt4             2.39836    0.55025 279.99999  4.3587 1.840e-05 ***
# speciesS2:trtt2   0.75106    0.77817 279.99999  0.9652 0.3353006    
# speciesS3:trtt2   1.20322    0.77817 279.99999  1.5462 0.1231826    
# ...snip


Thank you for this super helpful response! The case Im working with is somewhere between case 2 and 3. The seedlings were planted grew for an unknown amount of time but then died. As a result their heights were no measured. The likely reason for death is that they are planted outside of their natural range and high mortality was expected. I think including them as height = 0 would be incorrect as they have an unknown non-zero height. In this case would it be appropriate to remove all of S4 from the dataset or is it still possible to include them as NA (or missing) values?

@ThomsonHarris: It sounds like the data is Missing Not At Random (MNAR), or at least that you can't rule out MNAR. Unless you have covariates that can be used to compensate, if you include the remaining measurements you will introduce bias. The safest approach would be to remove the species altogether.
